# Run javascript on page load wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I've created a checkbox and an input field and added these to my WooCommerce checkout. The input field should be hidden when the checkbox is unchecked, while showing up once the checkbox is checked.

This is working fine when the checkbox is clicked - but on initial page load the checkbox is unchecked but the input field is showing.

How am I able to run the javascript on initial page load, such that the input field is hidden.

This is the code I have right now:

```
  
function conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field() {
   wc_enqueue_js( "
      $('#gift_wrap').change(function() {
         if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $('#personal_message_field').show();
         } else {
            $('#personal_message_field').hide();
         }
      });
   " );
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'on_load_script' );

function on_load_script()
{
  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() { conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field };        
    </script>
    <?php           
};
```

I'm learning javascript, so it's probably something silly. But everyone has got to learn along the way, so I decided I'll just post my question and learn.

Thanks!

Comment: `conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field` should be `conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field()` - to call a function you have to use the brackets.

Comment: Also I could be wrong but you seem to be trying to call a PHP function from JS?

Comment: `on_load_script` should be removed completely, the action you add should be `conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field`. And inside the JS code that is adding to the document, you should add a document ready handler, and inside _trigger_ the change event on that element.

Comment: Oke thanks for the input. I've tried to made an edit, but it's not working as I excepted.
`add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field', 9999 );

function conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field() {
   wc_enqueue_js("
      $('#gift_wrap').change(function() {
         if ($(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $('#personal_message_field').show();
         } else {
            $('#personal_message_field').hide();
         }
      });
   Window.onload = function() { conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field()};
   " );
};
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it in the wrong way.

1. `conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field` is a php function you can't call it inside script tag as JS function.
2. even if you call it using `<?php echo conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field(); ?>` it won't output any js code since you're using `wc_enqueue_js`
3. You have some issues with your jQuery code. in WordPress, you access jquery using `jQuery` not with `$` so you'll have to pass `jQuery` and use it as `$` using the function.

So you just need to write Js code using `wc_enqueue_js` within a function and hook that function on `wp_footer` you don't have to write `<script>` tag or anything else.

Here is the cleaned and correct code for you to use. You can `alert` something to ensure if it's working or not on page load.

#### UPDATE

**Note**: since you're using `wc_enqueue_js` which is the WooCommerce core function so you should make a `function_exists` check before using it because in any case you deactivate the plugin and you're using that function in the theme files it will bring an error.

```php
function conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field() {
    if ( function_exists( 'wc_enqueue_js' ) ) {
        wc_enqueue_js(
            "
            ( function( $ ) {
                window.onload = function() {
                    $( document ).on( 'change', '#gift_wrap', function() {
                        if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                            $( '#personal_message_field' ).show();
                        } else {
                            $( '#personal_message_field' ).hide();
                        }
                    } );
                };
            }( jQuery ) );
            "
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'conditionally_hide_show_checkout_field' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation @vijayhardaha, means a lot while learning along the way. I'm not so much used to mix JS and PHP as you noticed, but I see how things are supposed to work now.

Comment: @Neal I have added an extra note about using `function_exists` when you use a plugin function in the theme.